# Sort an observable array rxswift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have an observable Array and I bind it to a TableView. In that array I have different kind of categories and I want to sort the Array like that the items with the same category are grouped.

```swift
let observableItems = viewModel.getShoppingList().asObservable()
observableItems.bind(to: tableViewShoppingList.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "shoppingListCell", cellType: ShoppingListTableViewCell.self)) { row, element, cell in

    print(row)
}
```

Comment: Show some code on how you would sort this array if is _wasn't_ in an Observable.

Answer (score 0):

```
let observableItems = viewModel.getShoppingList().asObservable()
observableItems.map({ (items) -> [YourItemsType] in
   //Sort by group, category, etc.
   return items.sorted()
})
.bind(to: tableViewShoppingList.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "shoppingListCell", cellType: ShoppingListTableViewCell.self)) { row, element, cell in

    print(row)
}
.disposed(by: YOUR_DISPOSE_BAG)
```

Comment: What do you mean by group? Probably sections in UITableView?

Comment: I have different categorys and I want that the items which have the same category among themselves. I tried this code but it doesnt work.

Comment: let observableItems = viewModel.getShoppingList().asObservable()
        observableItems
            .map({ (items) -> [ShoppingListCoreData] in
                items.sorted { (category1, category2) -> Bool in
                    return category1.category == category2.category
                }
               return items.sorted()
            })

Comment: You can not sort items using equation. If .category property is String, use "return category1.category.compare(category2.category) == .orderedAscending"

Comment: Also, you don't need extra return items.sorted(). You got to return exactly the sorted array. Here what you trying to do: 1. sort with custom sorter, result had not saved to any variable. 2. return items.sorted() - returning other somehow sorted array.

Comment: Thank you rlly much. You saved my day

Comment: One more Question. When I want that the items where the status is false are at the beginning. What should I have to do ?

Comment: I tried this code but it doesnt work: return first.compare(property2.category ?? "") == .orderedAscending && property1.status < property2.status

Comment: Pseudo code: if status1 == status2 { return category1.compare(category2) == . orderedAscending } else {  return status1 < status2  }